# PostgreSQL: recursively join a second table

Tags: postgresql, recursion, common-table-expression

I'm struggling with recursion in PostgreSQL. I need to join a first table with a second one, and then recursively join within the second table. I looked at quite a number of examples, but most are about finding the parent records within a single table, and this has left me utterly confused.

Here's a minimal example with tables `thing` and `category`. Records in `thing` may or may not have a category:

| id | name | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a5 | 3 |
| 2 | passat | 2 |
| 3 | apple | NULL |

Records in `category` may have one or more parents in the same table:

| id | name | parent_category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | vehicle | NULL |
| 2 | car | 1 |
| 3 | coupe | 2 |

The result I'm looking for is the combination of all things with their categories, as well as the category level (1 for the direct parent, 2 for the level above).

| thing_name | category_name | level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a5 | coupe | 1 |
| a5 | car | 2 |
| a5 | vehicle | 3 |
| passat | car | 1 |
| passat | vehicle | 2 |
| apple | NULL | NULL |

I have a DB Fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b7V8ddragZZ9x2RsMkdFYn/5

```sql
CREATE TABLE category (
  id INT,
  name TEXT,
  parent_category INT
);

INSERT INTO category VALUES (1, 'vehicle', null);
INSERT INTO category VALUES (2, 'car', 1);
INSERT INTO category VALUES (3, 'coupe', 2);

CREATE TABLE thing (
  id INT,
  name TEXT,
  category INT
);

INSERT INTO thing VALUES (1, 'a5', 3);
INSERT INTO thing VALUES (2, 'passat', 2);
INSERT INTO thing VALUES (3, 'apple', null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CTE to join the tables, giving you a tree-like view of combined thing_categories, which you can then use with a normal recursive CTE.

---

```
with recursive join_thing_category as (
  select thing.id as thing_id,
  thing.name as thing_name,
  thing.category as thing_category,
  category.id as category_id,
  category.name as category_name,
  category.parent_category as parent_category
  from thing left join category on thing.category=category.id
  ),
recursive_part(n) as (
  select thing_id, thing_name, thing_category, category_id, category_name, parent_category, (0*parent_category) + 1 as level from join_thing_category
  union all
  select 1, thing_name, thing_category, cat.id category_id, cat.name, cat.parent_category as parent, level+1 as level from recursive_part rp cross join category cat
  where cat.id=rp.parent_category
  )
select thing_name, category_name, level from recursive_part order by 1, 2, 3 limit 1024;
```

| thing_name | category_name | level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a5 | car | 2 |
| a5 | coupe | 1 |
| a5 | vehicle | 3 |
| apple |  |  |
| passat | car | 1 |
| passat | vehicle | 2 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jAhEQ83pNL8iL2eM1QEiRQ/0)

The `(0*parent_category) + 1 as level` bit is so that things with no category get NULL as their level instead of 1.